# Is the following tree of SchoolContext correct?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Assume we have:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Is it correct to understand it as following tree?

```
SchoolContext
        |
        |__ DbSet<Student>
        |           |__ An entry1 (includes an Student entity, original values, current values, state of the entity)
        |           |__ An entry2 (includes an Student entity, original values, current values, state of the entity)
        |           |__ ...
        |
        |__ DbSet<Teacher>
                    |__ An entry1 (includes an Teacher entity, original values, current values, state of the entity)
                    |__ An entry2 (includes an Teacher entity, original values, current values, state of the entity)
                    |__ ...
```

As far as I know:

- **Student entity** is an instance of Student class.
- **original values** are begin values of that instance after we get the data, like `.Find()` method.
- **current values** are values after we modify.
- **state** tells the current state of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to have relationship between student teacher, then handle many to many relat. 
Example 1 teacher can have many student and one student can have many teacher so it will be many to many relationship.

That case create another class

```
class TeacherStudent
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }


    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TeacherStudent> TeacherStudents { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TeacherStudent> TeacherStudents { get; set; }
}
```

> and in your db context class override below method so TeacherStudent will became a FK relationship.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TeacherStudent>()
            .HasKey(s => new { s.TeacherID, s.StudentID });
    }
```