# Entity Framework: Mapping many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

During my project in which I make some sort of webshop, I've came across a problem with my .NET backend where I use Entity Framework Code First with Fluent API.

In my frontend, Orders can be made and are passed to my backend where they end up as a Order object (code below). This Order contains a User and a Dictionary where Items and their ordered quantities are stored. My current goal is to store those Orders in my database to retrieve an Order history.
My understanding is that by itself, EF can't map a Dictionary. Being a student and having done mostly frontend, I don't really know how to tackle this.

I've tried converting that Dictionary to a List of ItemWrappers (containing both the Item and the amount) and making 2 tables: Order (OrderId, UserId) and OrderItem (OrderId, ItemId, Amount). This converts the Many-to-Many (Users to Items and Order is derived from the relation attribute) to a One-to-Many (Order to OrderItem). 
I understand this from a purely database perspective. I could have managed if I were to write all the queries myself, but given that EF adds some abstraction to that, I am a bit lost. How do you suggest I do this?

The code is simplified to only show the class structure. Id is always generated on add and is used as primary key.

```
 public class User {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

 public class Item {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Order {
        public IList<OrderItemWrapper> ItemsList { get; set; }
        //Either one of these 2
        public Dictionary<Item, int> Items { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItemWrapper {
        public Item Item { get; set; }//Will use ItemId as key
        public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please go through my explanation for many-to-many relationship here.
[Is the following tree of SchoolContext correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881295/is-the-following-tree-of-schoolcontext-correct/56881564#56881564)

Comment: Would that automatically map the foreign keys?

Comment: You can check by inspecting your migration.

Comment: I've added it and it seems to work just fine. Thanks!